# How to insert/update an RDF file using Jena?

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena

I want to insert a node in my RDF file. I know that there is SPARQL insert/update syntax, but how to do this using Jena.  An example will be of great use.

Comment: I am with you. The examples are quite fuzzy.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you need to use SPARQL update? In Jena, nodes (resources or literals) aren't in the `Model` by themselves, but only by virtue of being part of a triple (i.e. `Statement`) in the model. If you have a `Model` object in your code, use one of the many variants of `addStatement` to add a given resource or literal into your graph.

#### Addendum

After your comment clarifying that you want to add to a file on disk, you could do as RobV says and amend the `Model` in memory, then write it out again. And this is really the correct way to do it. However, there is a quick-and-dirty workaround you might find helpful. If your file is in `Turtle` or `N-Triples` format, you can just append to the end of the file (which, obviously, you can't do in XML). So something along the lines of:

```java
File f = new File( "where.your.file.is" );
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( f, true );
out.write( ":john :loves :jane.\n" );
out.close();
```

would work. It's not really recommended, because you run the risk of (a) not having the correct namespace prefixes in place, (b) introducing syntax errors (since you're not using a Jena writer), and (c) creating duplicate triples, but it's sometimes a useful trick in a tight spot. Obviously you can only add information using this technique, not update or delete existing triples.

Directly appending to the end of an `N-triples` file is a valid and useful technique when collecting large volumes of data from ongoing logging or monitoring applications.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        m.read("/Users/heshanjayasinghe/Documents/A-enigmaProject/jena_Enigma/src/jena_enigma/Enigma.RDF", "RDF/XML");
        String NS="http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF#";

        Resource r = m.createResource(NS+"user8");//like subject
        Property p1 =m.createProperty(NS+"lname");
        Property p2 =m.createProperty(NS+"email");
        Property p3 =m.createProperty(NS+"fname");
        Property p4 =m.createProperty(NS+"password");


        r.addProperty(p1, "thathasara", XSDDatatype.XSDstring);
        r.addProperty(p2, "nt@gmail.com", XSDDatatype.XSDstring);
        r.addProperty(p3, "nipun", XSDDatatype.XSDstring);
        r.addProperty(p4, "t123", XSDDatatype.XSDstring);
      //   m.write(System.out,"thurtle");
          m.write(new FileOutputStream("/Users/heshanjayasinghe/Documents/A-enigmaProject/jena_Enigma/src/jena_enigma/Enigma.RDF"), "RDF/XML");
```

Comment: Does this code update the original rdf file or create a new rdf file?

Answer (score 0):

Use ARQs (Jena's SPARQL processor library) [UpdateFactory](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/update/UpdateFactory.html) to create an update and then the [UpdateExecutionFactory](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/update/UpdateExecutionFactory.html) to create an [UpdateProcessor](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/update/UpdateProcessor.html) which can evaluate the updates.

It's slightly more involved than this as you also need a dataset to evaluate the updates on. I honestly don't know how easy it is to create a dataset from a single model but can't imagine it being that difficult

Comment: Thanks RobV for your reply.

Actually, my concern is I have only a rdf file with me, not any data store, so is it possible to insert in that file?

Comment: Yes, what you would do is load that file into memory as a Jena `Model`, then create a dataset from that and apply the SPARQL Update over it before saving it back to a file again.  As Ian answer implies it may be easier to use the Model API methods like `addStatement()` to do this rather than SPARQL Update if your changes are simple

Comment: the link starting to invalid :( , i lead to same problem, but i use jena 3.1

Comment: I have fixed the links to work for current Jena, would googling for the class names given have been that hard?